# Implement Route listener in Javascript by Cloudflare worker

Tags: javascript, cloudflare

I am super new to Javascript and now try to implement the following functions to my website:

> Once the user input the website with **/hello** path, the web will
> response with `Hello world`  on the page

The skeleton framework of the `index.js` is as following:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
/**
 * Respond with hello worker text
 * @param {Request} request
 */
async function handleRequest(request) {
  return new Response('Hello worker!', {
    headers: { 'content-type': 'text/plain' },
  })
}
```

My goal to add a request handler so that the web can handle the `/hello` path with a `GET` request.

Answer (score 1):

Assign your worker to run on URL path match. This assumes you've already created the worker.

1. Open your domain in Cloudflare dashboard.
2. Go to the `Workers` tab.
3. Click `Add route`.
4. Specify the path url to match, e.g. `*.example.com/hello`. Select your worker. `Save`.

Open `example.com/hello` in the browser and it will respond with `Hello worker!`.